# Why is output of "top" command results cropped in crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, head

The xx.sh script contains the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash

TRACE_DIR="/opt/omspm/log"

#TRACE_FILE=process_yogunluk_`date +"%m%d%g"`.trc
TRACE_FILE=process_yogunluk_`date +"%d"`.trc

LOGPATH="$TRACE_DIR/$TRACE_FILE"

MAXLOGFILENUM=30

if ls $TRACE_DIR/process_yogunluk_*.trc 1> /dev/null 2>&1  ; then
  TOT_LOG="`ls $TRACE_DIR/process_yogunluk_*.trc | wc -l`"

  if [ $TOT_LOG -gt $MAXLOGFILENUM ] ; then
    TOTAL_REMOVE=`expr $TOT_LOG - $MAXLOGFILENUM`
    ls $TRACE_DIR/process_yogunluk_*| head -n $TOTAL_REMOVE | while read file ; do rm -f $file ; >done
  fi
 
fi


main(){
  echo "`date`"
  echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
  echo ""
  echo "`top -c -b -n1 | head -n 22`"
  echo ""
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo ""
  echo ""
}

main 2>&1 >>$LOGPATH
```

When I execute from command line `,root # ./xx.sh` the output is normal as below:

```
top - 11:19:13 up 412 days, 12:12,  3 users,  load average: 21.93, 20.09, 16.43
Tasks: 1004 total,   7 running, 996 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 22.4 us, 23.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 49.1 id,  4.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 99004272 total,   502072 free, 49047028 used, 49455168 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 76898304 total, 45502900 free, 31395400 used. 30473128 avail Mem 
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
27043 otn       20   0  372156 165076   1080 R  95.5  0.2   5144:59 /opt/perl/bin/perl ./pmd_ih_OTNE_1-19_
```

When I execute from crontab `*/1 * * * * xx.sh` the output is not normal as below:

```
top - 11:21:02 up 412 days, 12:14,  3 users,  load average: 15.32, 17.90, 16.02
Tasks: 995 total,   9 running, 985 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 33.5 us, 30.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 32.3 id,  1.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  2.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 99004272 total,   478640 free, 49020052 used, 49505576 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 76898304 total, 45514420 free, 31383880 used. 30491772 avail Mem 
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
27043 otn       20   0  372156 165076   1080 R 100.0  0.2   5144:18 /opt/perl/+
```

How can I prevent commands from cropping?

Comment: did you fixed your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason `top` behaves differently is because it is not ran from a terminal.

See this documentation about the parameter `-w` from `man top`:

> ```
>    -w  :Output-width-override as:  -w [ number ]
>         In  Batch  mode, when used without an argument top will format output using
>         the COLUMNS= and LINES= environment variables, if  set.   Otherwise,  width
>         will  be  fixed at the maximum 512 columns.  With an argument, output width
>         can be decreased or increased (up to 512) but the number of rows is consid-
>         ered unlimited.
>
>         In  normal  display mode, when used without an argument top will attempt to
>         format output using the COLUMNS= and LINES= environment variables, if  set.
>         With  an  argument,  output  width  can  only  be decreased, not increased.
>         Whether using environment variables or an argument with  -w,  when  not  in
>         Batch mode actual terminal dimensions can never be exceeded.
>
>         Note:  Without  the use of this command-line option, output width is always
>         based on the terminal at which top was invoked  whether  or  not  in  Batch
>         mode.
> ```

Maybe try to pass it to the `top` command with the maximum value (512).